# Add a few more values ​to the previous array in postman

Tags: javascript, automation, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

in my test i sholud compare response permission with my rolepermission_array variable in envirment

but there is diffrent , the reponse permission has 4 more permission because of it i should update my envirment
what should i do
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MslQN.png)

in this image my response has 4 more value

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R04mc.png)

"authenticated",
"manage_profile",
"manage_account",
"verify_email"

i should add this values to rolepermission_array

i update my code but still get error

[PreRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0oHf.png)

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3zfI.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrDad.png)

Comment: please add code and respone as code not as image. It is hard to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can add element to array using `push(element1, element2, ...)`
- To save array to environment, remember `stringify`
- To get array from environment, use `parse`

In tab Test

```
const res = pm.response.json();
const per = res.data.permissions;

const rolepermission = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("rolepermission_array"));

rolepermission.push("authenticated", "manage_profile", "manage_account", "verify_email");

pm.test("check permissions", () => {
    pm.expect(per).eql(rolepermission);
})
```

Comment: i think i dont work i dont know where is problem i will update pictures

Comment: Updated picture

Comment: @AmirMarezloo Are struggling at compare 2 arrays? Can you add response (json) to question?

Comment: @AmirMarezloo I understand your problem and have updated the answer. Please check it